# remotely remove item from arraylist after intersect

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a game project. So far so good, but i just stuck on ome basic thing and i cant find a solution and make it work properly. I decided to come here and ask you ppl of suggestions.

PROBLEM:

When the player comes to contact with a diamond, i suppose to remove the diamond from the level and from the arraylist containing all the objects in the world. What always happens i get an exception error message after remove() method called.

CODES:
1.Class with the list: EDIT_1

```
   private ArrayList<AbstractObject> objects = new ArrayList<AbstractObject>(); 

    public void removeObject(String name){           
    ArrayList<AbstractObject> newest = new ArrayList<AbstractObject>();
    ListIterator<AbstractObject> delete=objects.listIterator();
    while(delete.hasNext()){
        if(name.equals(delete.next().getName())){
            delete.remove();
        }
        else{
            delete.previous();
            newest.add(delete.next());
        }
    }
    objects=newest; 
}
```

2.Player class calling the removeObject method: EDIT_1

```
public void playerLogic(){
    fallingDown();        
       for(AbstractObject object : this.getWorld().getListOfObjects()){ <--------ERROR HERE
           if(this.intersects(object)){
               if(object instanceof FinishZone && points>=getWorld().getDiamondCount()){
                   if(!(getWorld().getManager().isMoreLevels())){
                       getWorld().getMenu().openMenu(true);
                   }                           
                   else{
                       this.getWorld().getManager().nextLevel();
                   }                       
               }
               if(object instanceof Diamond){
                   points++;                       
                   this.getWorld().removeObject(object.getName());
               }
            }
        }
}
```

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
at project.objects.characters.Player.playerLogic(Player.java:77)
at project.objects.characters.Player.update(Player.java:70)
at project.world.World.update(World.java:110)
at project.Main.update(Main.java:122)
at project.Main.run(Main.java:65)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I checked up some examples of removing items from arraylist but i havent find the difference.

EDIT_1:
So i figured out how to do it but i always get the error. I edited the removeobject code block. This worked good with a neutral list that i created for testing. I put all the items which i dont want to delete into a new list than ovewritten the old arraylist with the newest one. It worked with no exception error. When i made the same with the game list i want to edit it thrown the same error. 
Ill put there the render code too if maybe there is the problem...

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    if(menu.getChoice()==-1){
        menu.render(g);
    }
    else if(menu.getChoice()==0){
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        for(AbstractObject tempObj : objects){
            tempObj.render(g);
        }
    }                
}
```

FIXED:
Ill changed the starting list is ListIterator instead of putting items in arrayList before adding it to ListIterator. All methods changed to iterate. Working fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove object while iterating over a list.

One option - use `iterator.remove()` - if you iterate with iterator, not the "enhanced for loop". You'll need to slightly modify your loop code, but the functionality will be the same.

Another: Store all objects to remove in an **auxiliary list**, and remove them all at the end of the loop.

Comment: Wow. I havent though about that auxiliary list. I like that idea. Ill try that out.